# c# LINQ to object Autoincrement in subquery

Tags: c#, linq

Good Afternoon! Could anyone suggest how I can implement autoincrement in linq to object subquery which must be started from 1 on every group of main linq query? I have query

```
from student in students
group student by student
into keyStudents
select new StudentClass
{
  Student = keyStudent.Key,
  Subjects = from key in keyStudent
            select new SubjectClass
            {
              Subject = key.Subject,
              SubjectId = (stuck here)
            }
}
```

My result must be like this:

```
Student
 John
   1. Math
   2. Bio
 Fred
   1. Math
   2. Physics
   3. Bio
```

My query returns accurate data without SubjectId, but I need to show SubjectId as well. So the SubjectId is just index number started with one in every group.

Comment: Hi Ivan, can you post an example of what you're getting back right now? Also, can you tell us something about the source of the data? Are you querying a database? What does the Student class look like?

Comment: You can use the override of [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) that includes an index but you'll have to switch to method syntax for that one part.

Comment: To Glubus: unfortunately no. It's a query to generate xml-file based on xsd. In a topic it's just example of class to ask the question. For now I'm using one DataTable which contains all information needed to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use method syntax so you can use the override of `Select` that includes an index

```
from student in students
group student by student
into keyStudents
select new StudentClass
{
  Student = keyStudent.Key,
  Subjects = keyStudent.Select((x, i) =>
            new SubjectClass
            {
              Subject = x.Subject,
              SubjectId = i + 1,
            }),
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was writing up an answer as well but couldn't wrap my head around translating the query syntax to method syntax

Comment: Thanks. That's what I need. I just don't exact understand how lambda works. Like Select((x, i) =>
            new SubjectClass
            {
              Subject = x.Subject,
              SubjectId = i + 1,
            }) where x, I assume, is for keyStudent, but i - what's the type, why it compiled in int as the result - I'm very bad at lambda, thats why I avoid using this writing of LINQ :) But the more I read the more I understand that lambda writing of linq is more usefull then "sql" writing

Comment: In this case the `x` is basically what you called `key` in your query (I just didn't think that was a good name as it's not actually the key).  This lamba includes two input arguments `(x,i)` where the `i` is just an index that starts at 0.

Comment: Basically all Linq query syntax is compiled into the methods, but they don't have syntax to handle this override of `Select`.